# Export image file from bytea column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, export, bytea

I am trying to export an image file from a PostgreSQL database.The `users_data_circulation` table has a `photo` (bytea) column.

My command:

```
copy (select encode(photo,'hex') from users_data_circulation limit 1)
    TO '/tmp/imagetest.hext';
```

In operating system:

```
$> xxd -p -r /tmp/imagetest.hex > /tmp/imagetest.jpg
$> file /tmp/imagetest.jpg
/tmp/imagetest.jpg: ASCII TEXT
```

I can't open the `jpg` file. How can I convert this file to jpg?

```
devinim@devinimpostgresql:~$ hexdump -C /tmp/image.hex | more
00000000  5c 5c 33 37 37 5c 5c 33  33 30 5c 5c 33 37 37 5c  |\\377\\330\\377\|
00000010  5c 33 34 30 5c 5c 30 30  30 10 4a 46 49 46 5c 5c  |\340\\000.JFIF\\|
00000020  30 30 30 01 02 5c 5c 30  30 30 5c 5c 30 30 30 01  |000..\\000\\000.|
00000030  5c 5c 30 30 30 01 5c 5c  30 30 30 5c 5c 30 30 30  |\\000.\\000\\000|
00000040  5c 5c 33 37 37 5c 5c 33  34 31 5c 5c 30 30 30 5c  |\\377\\341\\000\|
00000050  76 50 49 43 5c 5c 30 30  30 02 5c 6e 5c 6e 01 5c  |vPIC\\000.\n\n.\|
00000060  5c 30 30 30 5c 5c 33 37  37 5c 5c 33 37 36 5c 5c  |\000\\377\\376\\|
00000070  30 30 30 21 50 69 63 74  75 72 65 20 45 6c 65 6d  |000!Picture Elem|
00000080  65 6e 74 73 2c 20 49 6e  63 2e 20 49 53 45 2f 53  |ents, Inc. ISE/S|
... continues like that
```

Comment: The content looks like it was generated by `encode(photo,'escape')` rather than `encode(photo,'hex')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a horrible idea to store jpegs in the database.

That said, if you want to get it out of the database, you can use psql. This gets it out as hex.

```
psql -t -A -o "/tmp/imagetest.jpg" -c \
  "SELECT photo FROM users_data_circulation LIMIT 1";
```

You may also want to check out the [large object.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo-funcs.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89072/discussion-between-peter-rader-and-evan-carroll).

Answer (score 0):

```
    DO $$ 
DECLARE   
   l_lob_id OID;
   r record; BEGIN

  for r in
    select data, filename from bytea_table

   LOOP
    l_lob_id:=lo_from_bytea(0,r.data);
    PERFORM lo_export(l_lob_id,'/home/...'||r.filename);
    PERFORM lo_unlink(l_lob_id);   
    END LOOP;

END; $$
```